Question on derivation of adjoint method
I have been working my way through a derivation of the adjoint method for solving optimisation problems, and had a query on a particular line of this derivation.
Link to the document being referred to: Link to adjoint method derivation
The particular part I was stuck on was on the first page, under section 1.2 - Derivation (first page, right hand side)....
....The expression $-f_{x}g_{x}^{-1}$ is a row vector times an $n_{x} \times n_{x}$ matrix....
Could someone please help me understand why this is the case? I understand the function $f(x)$ to take a vector of size $n_{x}$ and return a scalar, and I understand $g(x,p)$ to be a function that takes 2 vectors (of size $n_{x}$ and $n_{p}$) and returns a vector (of size $n_{x}$).
I would have thought that $f_{x}=\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ would be of size $n_{x}$, so like we are evaluating (the derivative of) $f(x)$ at all of the $n_{x}$ points, and that $g_{x}=\frac{\partial g(x,p)}{\partial x}$ would be of size $n_{x} \times n_{p}$, like we are evaluating (the derivative of) $g(x,p)$ at all $n_{x} \times n_{p}$ points.
Thank you in advance for any insights you can give. It's been many years since I was at university doing linear algebra, so any pointers you can give are also appreciated.

My answer (no guarantee that it's correct) follows this document, https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.336/adjoint.pdf .
We have
$$
\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\vec{p}}}_{1\times N_p}=\underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{p}}}_{1 \times N_p} + \underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}}}_{1\times N_x}\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}\vec{p}}}_{N_x\times N_p}
$$
We find an alternative way to write $\mathrm{d}\vec{x}/\mathrm{d}\vec{p}$, by using the constraints of the physical equation, namely,
$$
\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}\vec{p}}}_{N_x\times N_p}=-\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial \vec{x}}\right)^{-1}}_{N_x\times N_x}\underbrace{\frac{\partial g}{\partial \vec{p}}}_{N_x\times N_p}
$$
We plug this into the above system,
$$
\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\vec{p}}}_{1\times N_p}=\underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{p}}}_{1\times N_p} - \underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}}}_{1\times N_x}\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial \vec{x}}\right)^{-1}}_{N_x\times N_x}}_{\vec{\lambda}^T}\underbrace{\frac{\partial g}{\partial \vec{p}}}_{N_x\times N_p}
$$
The new variable $\vec{\lambda}^T$ has size $1\times N_x$ and is the solution to the system $\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial \vec{x}}\right)^T\vec{\lambda}=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{x}}\right)^T$. The cleverness of identifying $\vec{\lambda}$ is that it combines the $f_\vec{x}$ term and only a part of the $\vec{x}_\vec{p}$ terms, in such a way that we don't need to solve the matrix-matrix system of $\mathrm{d}\vec{x}/\mathrm{d}\vec{p}$ (the second equation give above) at all, and instead solve a much cheaper matrix-vector system. In a way, thus, we're simply changing the order of operations.
So, you correctly reasoned about the shape of $f_\vec{x}$, but incorrectly about the shape of $g_\vec{x}$. The function $g$ outputs a vector of size $N_x$, and we take $N_x$ of those vectors by varying the input components of $\vec{x}$.
